# How do you trace application memory leaks?

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks, memory-leak-detector

I have a large application which I run on a mobile device, written in C++ where it's UI is built using QT.

Do you know any utility that I can run to check for memory leaks while running the QT application on the mobile device?

Comment: Does `Valgrind` work with `Qt`? If so, then that should serve your purpose.

Comment: http://valgrind.org/info/platforms.html shows that arm support is medium (armv7 fairly complete), mips support is low, so valgrind can't be used on any mobile device.  If the code could run on a development machine, that would make working with valgrind more convenient

Comment: Can I run the qt application with valgrind as a parameter in command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the memory analizer that ships with Qt Creator. Just open your project, and on the left pane go to `Analyze`, then choose `Valgrind memory analizer` from the drop down menu and start your project.